# Non-javascript solution for helping older browsers support HTML5 tags

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I'm well aware of the caveats of using HTML5 and still needing to support older browsers (read IE8 and lower)... You need to add the shiv or Modenizr or something like that to make your pretty little site respect the  and  tags.

I'm happy with this, but someone said to me the other day that they didn't use HTML5 tags because obviously you needed JS to make IE8 play nicely with these. And I've seen what happens with Modenizr not loaded (I do ocassionally play around with advanced JS and break it all, which stops Modenizr loading).

Now I personally think this is a bit of an unnecessary statement because the useshare for browsers IE8 and lower who have JS turned off probably represents 0.000001% of your user base (especially given this was told to me by someone who does not support or test for IE7 and lower).

But I am wondering what solutions are out there if you want to support HTML5 tags in non HTML5 browsers WITH JS turned off. Or is my above assumption pretty accurate and it's really not worth thinking about?

Comment: Don't lose sleep over outdated browsers. If you want to drive on the highway, you need to use a car that can reach the minimum speed limit.

Comment: Haha that is an awesome analogy. Worry about mildly crotchety browsers. Don't worry about crotchety browsers with JS switched off; they are beyond help.

Comment: @zzzzBov While I agree, I would say that you can't just ignore them.  Unfortunately there are many people including very large businesses, which use older browsers.  I worked with a major british energy company recently who are still using IE7 and refuse to upgrade since it would cost them too much.  While this is annoying, it is unfortunately what a lot of companies do, and therefore ignoring older browsers is often a bad thing.

Comment: @JonTaylor - I wonder if that's one of the same major british energy companies that just announced a massive price hike? :(

Comment: @Spudley no, it isn't, however, even if it were this is really beside the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. There are no good solutions for using HTML5 tags in IE8 without using Javascript.

HTML5Shiv and Modernizr exploit the only known hack that can make IE recognise unknown tags in a way that is usable for a modern HTML5 website.

It is sort-of possible to do it by turning your entire document into xhtml and using a different namespace for the HTML5 tags -- see http://www.webstack.co.uk/html5_without_javascript_ie8/ for an example.

However, these techniques are not ideal, because IE has bugs with unknown tags that go beyond the basic one of being able to render them properly at all. There are several further bugs with them around areas such as dynamic content and printing that are dealt with by the HTML5Shiv hack, but not by the namespace hacks like this.

Bottom line: html5shiv is the answer. If you *really* need to support IE8 users who have Javascript disabled, consider not using HTML5 tags at all.